# PySpark Issues streaming from Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka, pyspark

I was trying to connect to the kafka(0.9.0) stream through PySpark for one of my applications. Facing following issue:

**Steps taken**

1. Started kafka using following commands

   ```
   bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
   bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
   ```
2. Using kafka-python library i have started kafka-producer. No issues with that, I was able to consume them back through Python.
3. Now if consume the same through pyspark(1.5.2) as shown in the following code:

   ```
   import sys
   from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
   from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
   from pyspark import SparkContext

   sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKafka")
   ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)

   zkQuorum, topic = 'localhost:9092', 'test'
   kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum,"my_group", {topic: 3})

   lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x.value)
   counts = (lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
      .map(lambda word: (word, 1))
      .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
   )

   counts.pprint()

   ssc.start()
   ssc.awaitTermination()
   ```

I executed the above code using following command

```
spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.5.2.jar test.py
```

I get the following error:

```
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9092, initiating session
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 157, boot = 156, init = 1, finish = 0
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO Executor: Finished task 3.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 5). 1213 bytes result sent to driver
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 5) in 958 ms on localhost (1/4)
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 305, boot = 304, init = 1, finish = 0
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 2). 1213 bytes result sent to driver
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 2) in 1115 ms on localhost (2/4)
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 457, boot = 456, init = 1, finish = 0
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 3). 1213 bytes result sent to driver
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 3) in 1266 ms on localhost (3/4)
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 306, boot = 304, init = 2, finish = 0
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4). 1213 bytes result sent to driver
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4) in 1268 ms on localhost (4/4)
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 4 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393) finished in 1.272 s
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 4.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
15/12/17 15:37:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 2 finished: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393, took 1.297262 s
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1450346841000 ms
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 3 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393) with 3 output partitions
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 6(runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393)
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(ShuffleMapStage 5)
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 6 (PythonRDD[15] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43), which has no missing parents
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(5576) called with curMem=100677, maxMem=556038881
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.4 KB, free 530.2 MB)
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(3326) called with curMem=106253, maxMem=556038881
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_3_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.2 KB, free 530.2 MB)
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on localhost:61820 (size: 3.2 KB, free: 530.3 MB)
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 3 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 3 missing tasks from ResultStage 6 (PythonRDD[15] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43)
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 6.0 with 3 tasks
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2024 bytes)
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 7, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2024 bytes)
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 8, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2024 bytes)
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6)
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 8)
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 7)
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 non-empty blocks out of 0 blocks
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 3 ms
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 2 ms
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 2 ms
C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\shuffle.py:58: UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling
15/12/17 15:37:21 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 158, boot = 154, init = 1, finish = 3
C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\shuffle.py:58: UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 298, boot = 294, init = 1, finish = 3
C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\shuffle.py:58: UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 448, boot = 444, init = 1, finish = 3
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 152, boot = 151, init = 1, finish = 0
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6). 1213 bytes result sent to driver
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6) in 784 ms on localhost (1/3)
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 320, boot = 318, init = 2, finish = 0
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 8). 1213 bytes result sent to driver
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 8) in 952 ms on localhost (2/3)
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 172, boot = 171, init = 1, finish = 0
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 7). 1213 bytes result sent to driver
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 7) in 957 ms on localhost (3/3)
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 6 (runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393) finished in 0.959 s
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 6.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
15/12/17 15:37:22 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 3 finished: runJob at PythonRDD.scala:393, took 0.987050 s
15/12/17 15:37:23 INFO ClientCnxn: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 3000ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting re
connect
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2015-12-17 15:37:18
-------------------------------------------

15/12/17 15:37:23 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1450346838000 ms.0 from job set of time 1450346838000 ms
15/12/17 15:37:23 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 5.780 s for time 1450346838000 ms (execution: 5.725 s)
15/12/17 15:37:23 INFO ReceivedBlockTracker: Deleting batches ArrayBuffer()
15/12/17 15:37:23 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1450346841000 ms.0 from job set of time 1450346841000 ms
```

Although the "Time" sections continue to appear.

No issues with pyspark or kafka, everything works perfectly well. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think error in this line:

```
zkQuorum, topic = 'localhost:9092', 'test'
```

**zookeeper port** should be **`2181`**

```
zkQuorum, topic = 'localhost:2181', 'test'
```

Source: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Without iterating the RDD, you can't process the each and every record by using of foreachRDD as DSstream will create the contineus RDDs.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from operator import add
import sys
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json
from kafka import SimpleProducer, KafkaClient
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

def handler(message):
    records = message.collect()
    for record in records:
        lines = record.map(lambda x: x.value)
        counts = (lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
                  .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) 
                 .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
                  )
         counts.pprint()

def main():
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)

    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
    kvs.foreachRDD(handler)

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```